# How close are we to the sensor pixel size limit?

Tags: sensor

Given the wavelengths of light we see, presumably there is some limit of pixel size below which we cannot resolve – i.e., packing four pixels into the area of one pixel would not be able to better resolve the location of an incipient photon.

But I'm not a physicist, so is this a relevant limit?

If so, how close to it are modern camera sensors?

Comment: Intuitively I would say we hit the diffraction limit long before wavelength but I've not worked out the math.

Comment: Well...I've read about getting Gigapixel on Large Format, so I'd say we're a whiles away from reaching a limit.

Comment: @SailorCire - the OP is talking about physical pixel size, not the number of them...

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft the two concepts are intrinsically linked, as diffraction is independent of sensor size when comparing images with the same depth of field.

Comment: As worded, only physical pixel size is relevant to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Nyquist Limit and what is its significance to photographers?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10755/what-is-the-nyquist-limit-and-what-is-its-significance-to-photographers)

Comment: @JamesSnell if the Nyquist Limit answers this question it is not obvious to me.  Even after puzzling over the answers to that linked question for some time I can't find a clear relationship.  I'm hoping that this question can stay open so a more lucid answer can be provided (or else an explanation of why none exists, or why this is identical to the question about the Nyquist Limit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're there.

Diffraction and color (wavelength) determine the physical limits on resolution at the sensor surface.  The best explanation of this (and the many related practical considerations for digital imaging sensors) is from http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/diffraction-photography.htm:

> Once two airy disks become any closer than half their width, they are
>   also no longer resolvable (Rayleigh criterion).  Diffraction thus sets
>   a fundamental resolution limit that is independent of the number of
>   megapixels, or the size of the film format. It depends only on the
>   f-number of your lens, and on the wavelength of light being imaged.

At an aperture of f/1.2 (which would produce the least diffraction) the Airy width for visible light is 1.6 microns.  For a typical sensor (which is designed as a Bayer array) in an otherwise perfect electro-optical system this means that pixels smaller than about 0.7 microns offer no increase in resolution.

We have the technical ability to mass-produce image sensors with pixels that small, but the smallest I've seen in production is just over 1 micron (common on cell phone cameras).  Note that premium production cameras still typically have a "pixel pitch" of a least 4 microns.  Apparently [the primary motivation for larger pixels is their improved signal-to-noise ratio](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2012/02/sensor-size-matters-part-2).  Presumably in a perfect electronic system that wouldn't be a factor and all sensors would sport pixels about 1 micron in width.

Comment: Brainstorming, how does the Bayer matrix affect all this? Handwaving slightly, it seems that our red/blue sampling frequency is only half the pixel frequency. Green is maybe sqrt(2)/2?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Yeah, that merits its own question, and I'd also like to know the answer.  I only mentioned the array type here because Cambridge in Colour made a point of it as an assumption in their calculation.